# I want when refresh the page show the tab active that is previosly selected, not the default one, using angular Js?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am new in angular Js. I have a page with tabs, i want when i selected the tab and refresh the page then same tab will be shown, not the default one. how can I do this. Thanks in advance.

```
    angular.module('TabsApp', [])
    .controller('TabsCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.tabs = [{
                title: 'One',
                url: 'one.tpl.html'
            }, {
                title: 'Two',
                url: 'two.tpl.html'
            }, {
                title: 'Three',
                url: 'three.tpl.html'
        }];

        $scope.currentTab = 'two.tpl.html';

        $scope.onClickTab = function (tab) {
            $scope.currentTab = tab.url;

        }

        $scope.isActiveTab = function(tabUrl) {
            return tabUrl == $scope.currentTab;
        }
    }]);
```

Comment: You need to tell us what you're using for tabs, and maybe show a lil code and markup

Comment: Try it with the documentation: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs

Answer (score -1):

Try using cookies to keep selected tab and retrieve it on page load